# outputting a file for user download with echo automatically adds carriage return and line feed

Tags: php

I have an php application which outputs a csv-file for the user to download.

The csv file is then imported by another application.

The other application crashes because the csv file has two empty rows at the end of the file where only a carriage return and a line feed occur.

Here is the code how i export the file:

```
$sData = getOutputString($aSomeArray);

file_put_contents('debug.txt', $sData, FILE_APPEND);

header('Content-Type: text/csv; charset=utf-8');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="output.csv"');
echo utf8_decode($sData);

function getOutputString($aSomeArray) {

    $sOutput = "";

    for ($aSomeArray as $oItem) {

        $aRow['0'] = $oItem->getSomeValue();
        $aRow['1'] = $oItem->getSomeOtherValue();
        $aRow['2'] = $oItem->getOneMoreValue();
        //More data is added to $aRow...

        if ($aRow !== null) {
            $sRow = implode(';', $aRow)."\r\n";
            $sOutput .= $sRow;
        }
    }

    return $sOutput;
}
```

Looking at the debug.txt i find the following result for $sData:

```
SomeValue;SomeOtherValue;OneMoreValue;...;...;...;[CR][LF]
SomeValue;SomeOtherValue;OneMoreValue;...;...;...;[CR][LF]
SomeValue;SomeOtherValue;OneMoreValue;...;...;...;[CR][LF]
```

This is how the file should be. But when i inspect the file itself with notepad++, i get the following result:

```
SomeValue;SomeOtherValue;OneMoreValue;...;...;...;[CR][LF]
SomeValue;SomeOtherValue;OneMoreValue;...;...;...;[CR][LF]
SomeValue;SomeOtherValue;OneMoreValue;...;...;...;[CR][LF]
[CR][LF]
[CR][LF]
```

The variable $sData does not have these additional [CR][LF]'s.

I already tried to echo without utf8_decode, but it makes no difference.

Can someone help me finding out where these additional [CR][LF] come from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay the problem was that my php-file had two extra columns after the php end-tag:

```
<?php
    $sData = getOutputString($aSomeArray);

    file_put_contents('debug.txt', $sData, FILE_APPEND);

    header('Content-Type: text/csv; charset=utf-8');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="output.csv"');
    echo utf8_decode($sData);

    function getOutputString($aSomeArray) {

        $sOutput = "";

        for ($aSomeArray as $oItem) {

            $aRow['0'] = $oItem->getSomeValue();
            $aRow['1'] = $oItem->getSomeOtherValue();
            $aRow['2'] = $oItem->getOneMoreValue();
            //More data is added to $aRow...

            if ($aRow !== null) {
                $sRow = implode(';', $aRow)."\r\n";
                $sOutput .= $sRow;
            }
        }

        return $sOutput;
    }
?>
/empty line 
/empty line
```

After i removed these lines, the extra [CR][LF] in my file disappeared.